# get table from a database using object_id

Tags: sql-server-2005

i want to get column names of table in sys.table using its object_id

regards
vivek

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[<your table name here>]')
```

If you know the object id, you can stick it in instead of `OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[<your table name here>]')`. Or, you could also stick a variable there.

Comment: i think OP already has the object_id of the table. so should OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[<your table name here>]') be replaced by <your object id here>?

Comment: Yea, it probably should. I just went ahead and included the syntax for getting the ID also anyways. I do have a note there saying you can just swap it in though.

Comment: If you hardcode the object_id you may be undone if the object is ever recreated for any reason. Should be better to use the `OBJECT_ID` function to return the Object id on run time.